# why my pdf is empty when upload more than 1.8MB even though it is success in react native expo?

Tags: javascript, react-native, pdf, file-upload, expo

```
  const encode = (uri) => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') return encodeURI(`file://${uri}`)
    else return uri
  }

const _pickDocument = async() => {
        try {
            let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({copyToCacheDirectory:true, type:'application/pdf'})
            console.log(result);
            if (result.type !== 'cancel') {
    
                let nameParts = result.name.split('.');
                let fileType = nameParts[nameParts.length - 1];
                
                var fileToUpload = 
                {
                    name: result.name,
                    size: result.size,
                    type: mime.getType(fileType),
                    uri: encode(result.uri),
                }
    
                console.log(fileToUpload);
                setDoc(fileToUpload);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    
    }

    const docFormData = new FormData()

    docFormData.append('file',doc);
    docFormData.append('ACTION', kategoriValue);
    docFormData.append('OUTLET', keyCustCode);
    docFormData.append('NIK', JSON.parse(keyUserNIK));

    const submitDoc= async()=>{
        const url = "your php url";
        if(kategoriValue==null){
            alert("bagian * wajib diisi");
            return;
        }
        setIsLoading(true)
        axios.post(url, docFormData,{
            headers:{
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
            }
        }).then(response=>{
            console.log(response)
            setIsLoading(false)
            alert(response.data)
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log(error)
        })

    }
```

this is my code for pick a document and it already gave an uri to work for

> Object {
> "name": "PA824_User_Manual.pdf",   "size": 2659219,
> "type": "application/pdf",   "uri":
> "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540egbertgan%252Fmodern-trade/DocumentPicker/e04a8b31-91b1-4b22-92c4-276bdd219a1f.pdf",
> }

the size in the example above is 2.6 MB and even though it is succeed but the pdf is somehow empty unless the size is less than 1.8MB.

and below is the response

> "responseURL": "your php url", "data": "Ada Kesalahan, file PDF
> corrupt", "status": 200,
> "timeout": 0,
> "upload": XMLHttpRequestEventTarget {},
> "withCredentials": true,

And this is the code in server side using PHP

```
    <?php 
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
  header("Content-type: multipart/form-data");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Disposition, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding");
    
    include "../koneksi.php";
  $pesan = '';
    
  $file = $_FILES['file'];
  $NIK = $_POST['NIK'];
  $OUTLET = $_POST['OUTLET'];
  $KATEGORI = $_POST['ACTION'];
  $DATE = date('Ymd');
  $NAME_FILE = $NIK.'_'.$OUTLET.'_'.$KATEGORI.'_'.$DATE.'.pdf';
  $KEY_IN = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

  $folderUpload = 'your folder';

  $target_file =$folderUpload . $NAME_FILE;
  $file_type = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    $sqlinsert = "insert query";
    if ($mysqli->query($sqlinsert) === TRUE) {
      $pesan='Data Berhasil Di Upload';
    } else {
      $pesan = "Error: " . $sqlinsert . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
    }
  }
  else
  {
      $pesan='Ada Kesalahan, file PDF corrupt';
  }
  
  echo json_encode($pesan);

?>
```

If someone knows something about this behaviour and can give me a hint I will be grateful.

Comment: @KJ so do you mean the uri is a text string ? and if so, can you give me an example on how to submit a file to PHP server ? Because frankly, I have searched many stackoverflow questions and expo community but still no luck. And also for the second comment, I already make sure with my coworker that he doesn't put any restriction. If there is a restriction, is there a keyword for it? sorry for the lack of knowledge